# Lock a single row in SQL Server from being selected

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use a lock, in SQL Server, such that if I select one record the locked record should not be returned by any other select query until the lock has been removed.

Below is the sample query:

SQL Table Name : Table1

Let Data in sql table be : only one column "Name"  having values ("ABC","XYZ","Test") in 3 respective rows

So, if I run a select query with some lock as below :

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1 -- Suppose this query returns ABC
```

Then If I run the same query in new query window (many times) but it should not return the value "ABC" until I remove the lock.

Comment: Yes, but probably not in the way you expect...You will need a flag in the table and the correct hints

Comment: @MitchWheat - Is there any way without having a flag in table

Comment: Locks are not flags. You should keep locks to an absolute minimum. Taking a lock on a table will BLOCK incompatible operations. You can use the READPAST hint in the SELECT queries but you'll still get awkward behavior with UPDATEs, INSERTs.

Comment: Uncommitted insert is the only way I know to do that. Not sure that's going to help you.

Comment: There is no *scalable* way to do this. You are asking for the classic checkin/checkout functionality but try to implement it using locks. Even if you change your DB to SNAPSHOT ISOLATION you'll put pressure on your `tempdb` and still not have what a couple of flags or a separate table would give you. Eg. CheckOutDate, *CheckedOutTo*, CheckInDate, stuff that you WILL need once you start "locking" rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM T WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) --disallow readers, lock on rows not pages or table
WHERE SomeCondition
```

This will not block concurrent readers in `SNAPSHOT` mode, though. You can't block those.

Answer (score -2):

For locking DML you can use "Select for Update". But if you want to lock select also, then you should do the locking explicitly with help of additional column and an trigger.

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is an Oracle/MySQL peculiarity that only works with cursors. And cursors kill your scalability

Comment: Not just cursor, it can be used in simple select as well.

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE doesn't even exist in SQL Server